# How to execute a dynamic LINQ expression

Tags: linq

Is it possible to dynamically buld and execute a LINQ expression? I.e. I have a collections of items that i want to query using LINQ but i want to create the LINQ statement at runtime and execute that LINQ query on my collection like this:

```
var myLINQExpression = GetLINQStatementFromFile(queryListFile);

var queryResult = myCollection.Where(myLINQExpression);
```

Comment: queryListFile is an XML file with a list of lambda expression such as
x => x.Name == “John”

Answer (score 3):

try [dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).